# Is it possible to access and modify a particular key's functionality in android system keyboard(not custom keyboard )..?

Tags: android, keyboard

I need to access and modify the functionality of a specific key in android system keyboard(soft keyboard), I'm not talking about creating a custom keyboard and adding it to android system, I need to access and modify a particular key in android soft keyboard.

Says if you press numeric key it will goto a different layout which contains numbers and special characters, what I need to do is to modify this functionality, it should go to my specify layout when numeric key is pressed.

Whether this is possible or not in android...??

Comment: You can do this with a KeyListener within your application.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you are looking to affect other applications, no, this is not possible.

Comment: Is it possible to add functionality to a key, I mean one more layout into numeric and special character layout ?

Answer (score 0):

To handle an individual key, you can implement onKeyUp()

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            moveShip(MOVE_LEFT);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F:
            moveShip(MOVE_RIGHT);
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_J:
            fireMachineGun();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K:
            fireMissile();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

This method is present in KeyEvent.Callback interface.

Comment: I'm not talking for particular application, I need to add functionality to softkeyboard itself

Comment: How to register this callback ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify "system" keyboard and its functionality. Keyboards are separate applications - imagine someone trying to modify your app, would you like to allow that?

And for your information - "system keyboard" is an separate application too. Depending on system distribution it can be anything, from the one implemented by Google to some producer specific one.